# Get to last app playing music on iOS8

Tags: audio, music, ios

In iOS6 and before, you could double-press the home button then swipe the bar of running apps right to get to music controls *and* an icon for the app last playing (or currently playing) music. This was very convenient to quickly get into Pandora/Slacker/Spotify/Beats/whatever and thumbs up or down a song.

In iOS8 (and 7 I'm told although I skipped it), it seems the only way to reach the app last playing is to scroll through the obscenely widely spaced full screen images of running apps and guess the one you think was last playing.

Is there any simple way to get to the app last playing or currently playing music?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sliding up the menu from the bottom of the screen gives you access to the currently playing music app (as well as to things like the Flashlight or Airplane mode toggle).

Touch the name of the song playing and it will take you to the app playing the song.

Comment: I'd seen that before but didn't realize you could get to the app playing the song. Just tried it again and figured out touching the name of the song takes you to the app. ...well hidden feature.

Comment: @Okuma.Tony That behaviour has been there since iOS 7 added control center.

Comment: I've now realized this doesn't seem to let you get to the app playing when it's most annoying -- such as when you get in the car, bluetooth connects, music automatically plays, but the music app isn't listed as running.

Comment: Also, AFAICT, you also have to hit _a solid part of a letter_ -- just anywhere on the line won't do. Very annoying. (None of this applies to iOS 11, of course.)